# why Azure web puslish does not use the specified C# version

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I am developing an asp.net webapi project. I set my project with C# 7.3 version. this project could build and run successfully locally. however when I try to deploy it on Azure. it will prompt the below error:

```
Feature 'enum generic type constraints' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.3 or greater.
```

it seems that Azure web publish process still uses the old C# version.
Does anyone meet the same situation?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you perhaps try building your local code in release mode to see if the problem still exists?

Ensure that C# 7.3 is included in any CPU and release property groups.
Right-click Your Project and select Properties from the drop-down menu.
If it isn't already chosen, click Build.
Select All Configurations from the drop-down menu.
Then select Advanced.
Change the language version

Comment: you're right . i am so stupid